# Add items to ActionBar in code, using AppCompat

Tags: android

I have a base class for my activities where I add the common action bar items.

```
public class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
```

In the activities where I extend my base activity I want to add some further items to the action bar.

```
public class ListActivity extends BaseActivity
{
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        addRefreshItemToMenu(menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    private void addRefreshItemToMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem refreshMenuItem = menu.add(R.string.menu_item_refresh);
        refreshMenuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_refresh);
        refreshMenuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
```

However MenuItem.setShowAsAction require API level 11, which is a problem since I use minSdkVersion="8".

How can I make this work using AppCompat?

Comment: please post your includes/imports

Comment: FYI you can inflate another menu xml file in the derived class. It will add the items and not overwrite them in case that's what you were expecting.

Comment: Ah thanks, gonna try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate menu xml for your `ListActivity` with `showAsAction="always"`

```
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  <item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
       android:title="@string/menu_item_refresh"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:orderInCategory="100"
      app:showAsAction="always" />
 </menu>
```

And, inflate this menu on your `ListActivity` which extends the `BaseActivity`.

```
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
      // menu only for this Activity
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
      // all other menus in BaseActivity will be added
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }
```

This will make sure you have the new menu only for this Activity and the common menus in the `BaseActivity`

Answer (score 1):

You must use [MenuItemCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/MenuItemCompat.html), because MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS appear only in API 11.

Comment: Could you give me an example of how to use it? Menu.add return a MenuItem.

Comment: Just change MenuItem to MenuItemCompat